# How to merge multiple groupby objects into columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes which are reflecting values per date e.g

```
Product : Amount
A : 5
B : 2
```

etc.... lets suppose i have 12 dataframes of such data and im using groupby 'Product' to get sum of amount.

now i would like to finally get one dataframe where coulmns would be dates and index would be Product - values each date would be results of groupby

What i have done so far is groupby one by one and finally merge it to dataframe however i dont think this solution is best way to achive this... any thoughts?

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example of 2/3 dataframes and the matching expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first combine all dataframes with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
your_dict_of_dfs = {'date1': df1, 'date2': df2}

out = (pd.concat(your_dict_of_dfs, names=['date'])
         .reset_index('date')
         .pivot_table(index='Product', columns='date', 
                      values='Amount', aggfunc='sum')
       )
```

Example output:

```
date        date1     date2     date3
Product                              
A        0.897580  0.129409  0.116364
B        0.002469  0.182804  0.276490
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import pandas as pd
    
# Assuming dfs is a list of your dataframes
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs)

grouped_df = combined_df.groupby(['Product', 'Date'])['Amount'].sum().reset_index()

pivoted_df = grouped_df.pivot(index='Product', columns='Date', values='Amount')

pivoted_df = pivoted_df.fillna(0)

pivoted_df = pivoted_df.reset_index()
```